# Set state on unmounted component outside of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

When setState is called after unmounting the Component in an asynchronous clickHandler causes warning in console:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
```

See [Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/clickhandlerremovecomponent-d6kfy)

```
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)
  return {show && <Button
          text="Click to remove"
          clickHandler={() => setShow(false)}
        /> }
}
function Button({ text, clickHandler }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(text);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    await clickHandler();
    setState("I was clicked");
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}> {state}</button>;
}
```

Clicking the `click to remove`  button will unmount the button and then update the state.

The goal is to set the state of the Button Component *after* the asynchronous call. This asynchronous call can but does not have to trigger the Button being unmounted. I am looking for a way to opt out of the `setState` after the asynchronous call.

I do not see how this can be avoided in a nice way using useEffect.

There are two possible workarounds in the example.
One uses `useRef` to check if the component is unmounted (like recommended in [#14369 (comment)](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14369#issuecomment-468605750) ). This does not feel very react-like.

The other workaround uses the recommended `useEffect` guard variable (like [#14369 (comment)](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14369#issuecomment-468267798)). But to get the clickHandler out of `useEffect` the clickHandler is stored in a state. However, to get a function into a state it needs to be wrapped inside another function, as the `setState` function of `useState` will call a function given as an argument.

Comment: My suggestion would be to just turn your component into an extension of the React Component class and use `componentWillUnmount`. But my actual suggestion is to figure out why you are having this side effect and fix that rather than just patching this issue.

Comment: can you please add the relevant code to your question?  The codesandbox link is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question, I have no idea why it didn't get any attention. I believe I found a nice solution, let me know if you think this solves the problem. The solution is based on the fact that we can use `useRef()` without using the ref attribute anywhere.

We define two custom hooks, `useIsMountedRef` and `useStateWithMountCheck`. You can use the latter just like the `useState`hook and it will just ignore any demanded state change if the component is not mounted anymore.

```
function useIsMountedRef(){
  const ref = useRef(null);
  ref.current = true;

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      ref.current = false;
    }
  });

  return ref;
}

function useStateWithMountCheck(...args){
  const isMountedRef = useIsMountedRef();
  const [state, originalSetState] = useState(...args);

  const setState = (...args) => {
    if (isMountedRef.current) {
      originalSetState(...args);
    }
  }

  return [state, setState];
}
```

[Checkout the Sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/clickhandlerremovecomponent-5o54q?fontsize=14)

Comment: @palortoff Can you explain why you object in general to the usage of useRef? The traditional lifecycle methods in class-style components rely on similar constructs as far as I know. Don't you think useStateWithMountCheck feels "react-like"?